# how to use context.Done() with nested http middleware

Tags: http, go

I would like to know how to properly implement/use [context.Done()](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) method when using it within an [HTTP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP) server and implementing [middleware](https://violetear.org/post/middleware/), my goal is to cancel subsequent events when a client disconnects across nested middleware.

For testing I created the following code, I don't know if is the correct way of doing it since I had to create a [channel](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) within the [HandleFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.HandleFunc) and a [goroutine](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines) to handle the requests, putting all this together within a [select](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) wait statement.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    log.Println("handler started")
    defer log.Println("hander ended")

    ch := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello")
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }()

    select {
    case <-ch:
    case <-ctx.Done():
        err := ctx.Err()
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusPartialContent)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Basically here the request simulates load by sleeping 5 seconds, and then prints `Hello`, but if the client cancels the request, for example:

```
$ curl 0:8080
```

And then pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd> +  <kbd>c</kbd>, this will be loged:

```
2017/07/07 22:22:40 handler started
2017/07/07 22:22:42 context canceled
2017/07/07 22:22:42 hander ended
```

This works but wondering if this pattern (the goroutine and select) should be used in every nested handler or if there is a better way of implementing this.:

```
ch := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    // some logic   
    ch <- struct{}{}
}()

select {
case <-ch:
case <-ctx.Done():
    err := ctx.Err()
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusPartialContent)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> At Google, we require that Go programmers pass a Context parameter as the first argument to every function on the call path between incoming and outgoing requests.
>
> -- [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context)

Comment: you pass the context but do you still need to create the `select {
case <-ch:
case <-ctx.Done():
    err := ctx.Err()
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusPartialContent)
}` ? or how do you handle when client disconnects ?

Comment: I read it as each async process needs to race the context and exit early. In serious apps you probably need a timeout child context anyway.

Comment: Could you please share an example or write a basic implementation, basically wondering if all the code for the handler goes within a goruine: `go func(ch chan struct{}) {....`